# Erro datepicker jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery, asp.net

tenho o script definido da seguinte forma:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/ >
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var textbox = '<%=TextBoxDataInicial.ClientID%>';
        var textbox = '<%=TextBoxDataFinal.ClientID%>';
        $('#'+textbox).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
            monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
            nextText: 'Próximo',
            prevText: 'Anterior'
        })
    });

</script>
```

e o controlo da seguinte forma:

```
<td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDataInicial" runat="server" Width="120px" MaxLength="24" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorDataInicio" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDataInicial" ErrorMessage="Campo necessário!">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDataInicial" ErrorMessage="Data Inválida!(##/##/####)" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Smaller" ValidationExpression="(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/((1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2})"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>

<td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDataFinal" runat="server" Width="120px" MaxLength="25" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDataFinal" ErrorMessage="Data Inválida!(##/##/####)" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Smaller" ValidationExpression="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/((1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2})"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
```

Comment: Tem algum erro na consola? pode explicar melhor "não funciona" ? Não devia estar a usar o textbox com `ID="datepicker"` aqui `$('#' + textbox).datepicker({` ?

Comment: Não dá erro nenhum. Apenas quando clico na textbox não aparece o calendário.

Comment: Porquê `$('#' + textbox)` e não `$('#datepicker')` ? Quantos datepickers vai ter?

Comment: em Pelo menos duas Textbox

Comment: @user6018 De qualquer forma, confirme se o valor de `textbox` está correto (eu entendo que ele deve retornar o ID do seu elemento, mas ele retorna com ou sem o `#`?), imprimindo-o no console. Pois se não há erro nenhum, é provável que o seletor é que esteja errado...

Comment: pode colocar o html das duas textboxes?

Comment: vou editar a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, reparei que ce tá redefinindo o valor do `textbox`. 
Na primeira linha dentro do `$(document).ready({})`, você pôs

```
var textbox = '<%=TextBoxDataInicial.ClientID%>'
var textbox = '<%=TextBoxDataFinal.ClientID%>'; // Aqui, o textbox vai ser substituido por outro ID.
```

Na prática, seria equivalente a:

```
var textbox = 1;
var textbox = 2;
```

De modo que, quando entra em

```
 $('#'+textbox).datepicker({
```

o valor vai ser equivalente a

```
 $('#2').datepicker({
```

E somente o segundo datepicker (se as configurações do dp estão corretas) será interpretado.

Como você quer que os dois datepicker sejam interpretados, você *pode* fazer o seguinte (é o como eu faria):

1) Enclausule os dois (ou mais) datepickers dentro de um obj jQuery.

```
var objDP = $("#<%=TextBoxDataInicial.ClientID%>,#<%=TextBoxDataFinal.ClientID%>");
//Desta forma, o seletor vai buscar os dois inputs de uma vez.
```

2) Execute o interpretador do DatePicker, do mesmo jeito que ce teria feito antes.

```
objDP.datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior'
    })
```

Lógico, isto tudo dentro do `$(document).ready(function(){})`

**UPDATE** Agora que eu vi a resposta do Jorge B. Mas acho que colocar os dois em um seletor só melhora a visibilidade do código, além de permitir que cê coloque MAIS inputs, recebendo o mesmo template de datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma simples e sucinta de fazer isto seria criando uma classe específica para os Datepicker, e adicionar esta classe somente nos elementos que você quer tal funcionalidade.

**Ex:** `$(".datepicker").datepicker( ... );`

Adicione seu código PHP, JSP, ou o que seja uma função que caso seja necessário tal campo ser datepicker escreca tal classe nele:

```
<input type="text" name="data" class="datepicker">
```

Logo toda vez que precisar de um outro nas suas telas, você precisaria só adiciona tal classe no campo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso 2 *datepicker* também, o que optei por fazer foi criar no `script` 2 funções, uma para cada *picker*:

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
     ...
)};

$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
     ...
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que você está definindo a variável `text` duas vezes.

```
var textbox = '<%=TextBoxDataInicial.ClientID%>';
var textbox = '<%=TextBoxDataFinal.ClientID%>';
$('#'+textbox).datepicker({ ...
```

Para resolver o seu problema, tente concatenar as variáveis e chamar de uma única vez:

```
var textbox = '#<%=TextBoxDataInicial.ClientID%>,#<%=TextBoxDataFinal.ClientID%>';
$(textbox).datepicker({ ...
```

Ou:

```
var textbox = '#<%=TextBoxDataInicial.ClientID%>';
textbox += '#<%=TextBoxDataFinal.ClientID%>';
$(textbox).datepicker({ ...
```

Our ainda:

```
var textbox = '<%=TextBoxDataInicial.ClientID%>';
$('#'+textbox).datepicker({
    // ...
});

textbox = '<%=TextBoxDataFinal.ClientID%>';
$('#'+textbox).datepicker({
    // ...
});
```